# Custom Button URL using IF condition found on Salesforce doc but not working

Tags: formula, custom-button, url, if

I am trying to create a custom button redirecting either to :

- the correct LinkedIn profile if the LinkedIn ID is filled
- a LinkedIn search using First Name & Last Name

So far, here is what I have :

```
{!
IF(len(Contact.LinkedIn_ID__c)=0,
"http://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/keywords="&Contact.FirstName&"%20"&Contact.LastName,
"http://www.linkedin.com/in/"&Contact.LinkedIn_ID__c)
}
```

Whenever I click the button, I am redirected to a new Salesforce page with the following error : "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app."

I have found a [Salesforce doc using the same kind of formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) :

```
{! 
IF(Sample.BillingCountry = "US", 
"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=​"&Sample.BillingStreet&​
"+"&Sample.BillingCity&"+​"&Sample.BillingState&"+​"&Sample.BillingCountry, 
(IF(Sample.BillingCountry = "UK", 
"http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=​"&Sample.BillingStreet
&​"+"&Sample.BillingCity&​"+​"&Sample.BillingCountry, 
"http://maps.google.com"))) 
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (both Classic and Lex)

- Detail Page button
- Behavior: Display in new Window
- Content Source: URL

  ```
  {!IF(ISBLANK(Contact.LinkedIn__c),
    URLFOR('http://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people', NULL, [keywords=Contact.FirstName & ' ' & Contact.LastName]),
    URLFOR('http://www.linkedin.com/in/' & Contact.LinkedIn__c,NULL)
    )
   }
  ```